# cv2.imread() gives diffrent results on Mac and Linux

Tags: python, opencv

`cv2.imread(JPG_IMAGE_PATH)` gives different arrays on Mac and Linux.

This may be because of the reason described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) (see Note).

Is there any solution to get the same arrays on Mac and Linux?

Comment: Avoid lossy formats is probably the best advice.

Comment: You can always try different libraries to read. Like [imageio](https://github.com/imageio/imageio) or any lib mentioned for io within [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/). Sadly i can't guarantee that they will behave the same on each OS. The warning in the docs would drive me crazy. It's not what i expected with such a common image-format. Another approach would be: use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to decode the jpeg to some lossless format like png, then proceed. Or maybe even better: use the official jpeg-decoder to create some intermediate bmp.

Comment: @sascha skimage.io.imread() gave the same result on Mac and Ubuntu. But I don't yet know whether it works for any kind of images or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can build opencv & libjpg from source in both linux & mac. Using cmake you can build opencv with libjpg support (from source code). Hope this will give you same result.

```
cmake -DWITH_JPEG=ON -DBUILD_JPEG=OFF -DJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR=/path/to/libjepeg-turbo/include/ -DJPEG_LIBRARY=/path/to/libjpeg-turbo/lib/libjpeg.a /path/to/OpenCV
```

One of the libjpg source: [link](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo)

Currently it is giving different result due to different version of libjpg in these OS.